# Vim only takes up half the screen in tmux

Tags: vim, tmux

When I run vim in tmux, it only takes up half the screen (usually the left half). I would like vim to use up the whole screen, but don't know how.  Tmux still seems to consider the entire screen as one pane though - when I press Ctrl+b q, the pane number ('0') appears in the middle of the screen.  Any ideas on what the issue is (I'm not sure if it's tmux or vim)?

Comment: Weird. What is the value of `$ echo $COLUMNS` outside and inside of tmux and the value of `:echo &columns` in Vim? Also what is the value of `$ echo $TERM` in and outside of tmux?

Comment: Outside tmux: 202 (columns)   xterm-256color

Comment: Inside tmux: 202 (columns) screen. And 
inside vim, :echo columns returns 100

Comment: I don't know why, but I think I found a fix by putting `set term=xterm` into my .vimrc.  Thank you for the clue!

Comment: The recommended `TERM` setting for tmux is `screen-256color`. Add this line to `~/.tmux.conf`: `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"`.

Answer (score 0):

As @user977588 suggests, the fix here is to add:

```
set term=xterm
```

... to .vimrc.

EDIT: if you wish to retain syntax coloring, instead use:

```
set term=xterm-256color
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this problem today. The above answer didn't work. I had to add these lines in my .vimrc to fix (adjust to your screen size):

```
set lines=52
set columns=211
```